# exec() не работает внутри def

Tags: python, python-3.x, exec

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой - внутри def не работает должным образом exec()

---

Вот рабочий кусок кода:

```
foo = 'Hello World!'
exec('bar = %s' % 'foo')
print(bar)

# Hello World!
```

А вот нерабочий:

```
def func():
  foo = 'Hello World!'
  exec('bar = %s' % 'foo')
  print(bar)
func()

# name 'bar' is not defined
```

Подскажите, что я делаю не так?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463306/how-does-exec-work-with-locals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте:

```
def func():
  foo = 'Hello World!'
  exec('bar = %s' % 'foo',locals(),globals())
  print(bar)
func()
```

Передавайте `locals()` как параметр `globals` и `globals()` как параметр `locals`.

`exec ()` устанавливает `bar` как глобальный, но читает`foo` как глобальный.

`foo` является локальным, поэтому `locals()` нужно передавать для `globals`.

Точно так же, `bar` используется как локальный, поэтому передайте `locals ()` как `globals`, если не требуется вне функции.

Извините, если это сбивает с толку. Я англичанин.

Comment: Последнее предложение не понятно, возможно вы имели в виду "Передавайте локальные переменные как locals() и глобальные как globals()"?

Comment: См редактировать